# Polyhedra intersection

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes

If $A$ and $B$ are polyhedra, how do we show that the intersection $A ∩ B$ is a polyhedron.

Does the same apply if they are both polytopes, will the intersection $A ∩ B$ also be a polytope?

The definition for a polyhedron is: A polyhedron $P ⊆ R^n$
is defined as the solution set of a system of linear
inequalities. Thus, P has the form
$P =$ {$x ∈ R^n: Ax ≤ b$}

Comment: Hint: the set of points in the intersection $A\cap B$ is the set of all points that fall into the solution set of $A$ and into the solution set of $B$. It may be helpful to break down the matrix inequality $\mathbf{M}\vec{x} \leq \vec{b}$ into a set of inequalities $\vec{M_i}\cdot\vec{x}\leq b_i$.

Comment: For polyhedron, it is obvious from the definition. What is your definition of polytope? All you need will be in Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $P_1 = \{x:Ax\leq a\}$ and $P_2=\{x:Bx\leq b\}$ are the two polyhedron.
Then
$$
P_1\cap P_2 = \{x:Ax\leq a,\;Bx\leq b\} = \Bigg\{x : \begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}x \leq  \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\} = \{x:Cx\leq c\}
$$
where $C = \begin{bmatrix}A\\B\end{bmatrix}$ and $c=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$.
Thus $P_1\cap P_2$ can be represented as a polyhedron.